# Update multiple rows in a single query php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, selected

I am trying to update multiple rows using the following script but the problem is what it changes all the data entries in the desired column . Instead I want only the selected rows to be changed. 
Here is my code:

```
  <?php
  $query = mysql_connect("localhost","root","toor");
  mysql_select_db("busticket",$query);
  $result=mysql_query("Select * from ticket_reservation WHERE   validate_status='Yes'") or die(mysql_error());
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
   echo "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' id='name'  name='name[]'    value=".$row['id']."</td><td>".$row['userid']."</td><td>".$row['busid']."</td> <td>".$row['numberofseats']."</td></tr>";

 }
 echo"<tr><td><input type='submit' name='submit' Value='Validate Tickets'> </td></tr>";
 if(isset($_POST['name']))
 {
 $Name=$_POST['name'];
 foreach($Name as $N)
  if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["submit"]!="") {
   $usersCount = count($_POST["name"]);
   for($i=0;$i<$usersCount;$i++) {
   mysql_query("UPDATE ticket_reservation set validate_status='Yes'");
  }

   ?>
```

Comment: what is with the foreach ? what do all the echo's of $qry suggest that you are doing? Then why are you surprised and even here ?

Comment: It means for each selected row . there are no errors returned . As I mentioned it changes all columns in the table....I want only selected ones to be...perhaps it is not checking which ones are selected...

Comment: can you add 2 queries echoed

Comment: it does not change all columns in the table

Comment: Your condition is `if(isset($_POST['name']))` so it will update all posted names, even if checked or not. You should try to use `ajax` or `js` to do so.

Comment: also, get `validate_status` versus `validate-status` cleaned up. Who knows what math expression explosion that could create. Also, don't connect as root, and don't use mysql_* library. So basically destroy this code.

Comment: `print_r($Name);` to see only checked inputs are being posted or all

Comment: why you want update rows with `Yes` that have already `Yes` in `validate_status` ?? `$result=mysql_query("Select * from ...WHERE   validate_status='Yes'` **and** use also `WHERE` in your update statement. ::: `("UPDATE ticket_reservation set validate_status='Yes' WHERE id=$N");`

Comment: also you have forget `>` closing input tag : `echo "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' id='name'  name='name[]'    value=".$row['id']."</td>`

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
  $query = mysql_connect("localhost","root","toor");
  mysql_select_db("busticket",$query);
  $result=mysql_query("Select * from ticket_reservation WHERE   validate_status='Yes'") or die(mysql_error());
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {?>
   <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='name'  name='name[]' value="<?echo $row['id'];?>"></td>
    <td><?echo $row['userid'];?></td>
    <td><?echo $row['busid'];?></td>
    <td><?echo $row['numberofseats'];?></td>
  </tr>
 <?}?>
 <tr><td><input type='submit' name='submit' Value='Validate Tickets'> </td></tr>
 <?
 if(isset($_POST["submit"])
 {
 $Name=$_POST['name'];
 $usersCount = sizeof($Name);
 for($i=0;$i<$usersCount;$i++) 
 {
    $ID=$Name[$i];
    mysql_query("UPDATE ticket_reservation set validate_status='Yes' WHERE id='$ID'");
 }}?>
```

Comment: you do the same mistake as OP `foreach($Name as $N)` is enough don't do a nested loop `for($i=0;$i<$usersCount;$i++)` it is unnecessary and wrong.

Comment: also do not test `if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["submit"]!="")` again and again in a loop

Comment: oh @moskito-x. Sorry. Edited

Comment: looks OK now . Please inform OP what have you done and why

Comment: Hi @moskito-x. I will thanku for not downvoting my answer, even if it was having 2-3 errors. Instead, you helped me to rectify it. Nowadays, people busy in downvoting. But, you are different Man. God Bless You Man. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

The checkboxes must have a specific Name so that you can know what to update in the database.

```
<input type='checkbox' id='name'  name='name[1]' value=".$row['id'].">
<input type='checkbox' id='name'  name='name[2]' value=".$row['id'].">
```

Also you are missing a ">" after value

Comment: How can I do that I have to get all the usernames and Ids dynamically do you mean I must get all the entries manually ? i.e. by name[1], name[2] . That would be impractical if there are a thousand entries